# Paginate with Kaminari not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, pagination, kaminari

I am trying to use basic Kaminari to do some pagination, but I am having trouble getting it to work properly.

I have installed the Kaminari gem and then in my controller I have the following code:

```
def new
    @guestbook = Guestbook.new
    @guestbooks = Guestbook.all.limit(5).page(params[:page])
end
```

In my associated new view I have this code...

```
<%= paginate @guestbooks %>

<div class="span1">
    <% @guestbooks.each do |g| %>
        <br/>
        <h4><%= g.name %>, <%= g.created_at %><br/></h4>
        <%= g.message %><br/>......
```

However when I reload my page I do not see any pagination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use this in your controller:

```
@guestbooks = Guestbook.all
@guestbooks = Kaminari.paginate_array(@guestbooks).page(params[:page]).per(5)
```

And add this in your view:

```
<%=paginate @guestbooks%>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to have the same instance variable name within a method?

Comment: Yeah, it will just overwrite the first one.

Comment: Thanks. The pagination is working now, but when I go the next page, I don't see any of the guestbook entries? On this page I see them http://localhost:3000/guestbooks/new, but when I navigate to http://localhost:3000/guestbooks/new?page=2, nothing is there?

Comment: This will load all records.

Answer (score 3):

I completely support @Yang answer, and also I would suggest to make sure you have given min number of entries which is greater than the per page value.

for example:

```
def index
@posts = Post.page(params[:page]).per(10)
end
```

In this case: you must be created more than ten entries to get the pagination.